# Total events found

Tags: powershell

I'm developing a script where I look for specific windows events. I would like the script to display the total of events found at the end of the script.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
   LogName='Application'
   Level= 4
   StartTime=(Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
}
```

Comment: if you assign that to a $Var, then you can use `$Var.Count` to get the count of the items returned. you MAY need to wrap the `Get-WinEvent` call in `@()` to force it to be an array ... sometimes single returned items give an incorrect zero count ... [*frown*]

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: i see that I.TDelinquent answered your question ... great! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lee has pointed out in the comments, the two easiest ways to go about this would be:

```
$var = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
   LogName='Application'
   Level= 4
   StartTime=(Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
}
$var.Count
```

and

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
   LogName='Application'
   Level= 4
   StartTime=(Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
}).Count
```

Comment: If you want to be fancy, use the first one and create a custom string:
`Write-Host "There were {0} entries by {1} different applications" -f $var.count $var.ProviderId.count`

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I needed.

Comment: @BryanAlmeida Please upvote and "Mark as answer" the appropriate response :)